ASCII doc - display special characters in table column
I would place the following regexp: ^(?!\s)[^0-9!#|$^`\\~_%&\"'(){}*+,./:;<=>?@\]\[]*(?<!\s)$ in the ASCII doc table.
Example Ascii doc:
[%autowidth]
|===
|Path|Type|Validation|Rule|Description

| type
| String
| Required
| <here I would like to place it>
|Placeholder

|===

I tried many ways to handle that but with no results. I used for e.g."

'`' characters at the begin and end of regexp
literal clause
pass::[] clause

But all of this methods use special characters that are also in my regex. Do you have an idea how can I display any string using Ascii doc functionalities?

Just convert your line to the HTML codes:
&#x5e;&#x28;&#x3f;&#x21;&#x5c;&#x73;&#x29;&#x5b;&#x5e;&#x30;&#x2d;&#x39;&#x21;&#x23;&#x7c;&#x24;&#x5e;&#x60;&#x5c;&#x5c;&#x7e;&#x5f;&#x25;&#x26;&#x5c;&#x22;&#x27;&#x28;&#x29;&#x7b;&#x7d;&#x2a;&#x2b;&#x2c;&#x2e;&#x2f;&#x3a;&#x3b;&#x3c;&#x3d;&#x3e;&#x3f;&#x40;&#x5c;&#x5d;&#x5c;&#x5b;&#x5d;&#x2a;&#x28;&#x3f;&#x3c;&#x21;&#x5c;&#x73;&#x29;&#x24;

It works with Ascii doc version 2.0.10

Do you want the regex to look like regular prose? If so, place it directly in the table markup and escape select markup characters with a backslash:
| \^(?!\s)[^0-9!#\|$^`\\~_%&\"'(){}*+,./:;<=>?@\]\[]*(?<!\s)$

Here, the initial caret is escaped to prevent superscript, and the pipe is escaped to prevent introducing a new table cell.
If you want the regex to show as inline monospace, do the same thing but surround the regex with unconstrained inline monospace markup "``":
| ``\^(?!\s)[^0-9!#\|$^`\\~_%&\"'(){}*+,./:;<=>?@\]\[]*(?<!\s)$``

Using HTML entities is another choice that can work, but makes the content harder to maintain.
AsciiDoc has a feature called Literal Monospace that would be the correct solution if your regex does not contain a plus symbol. Since there is a plus, it doesn't work like you expect.
The pass::[] macro could be used, but escaping the regex is harder.
